# Joi is throwing error while validating mongoose object -

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

When I create an object of type Contact (which is a model of MongoDB schema) it throws some weird error as below. My purpose of using Joi is for Client-side validation aka incoming request.

Here auth is a middleware that is validating jwt and fetching out the id from jwt.

It is showing weird kind of error like - **"$__" is not allowed. "isNew" is not allowed. "errors" is not allowed. "_doc" is not allowed. "$locals" is not allowed. "$op" is not allowed **

```
router.post('/',auth,async (req,res)=>{
try{
// console.log(`contact - ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`);
let contact = new Contact({
  firstName : req.body.firstName,
  lastName : req.body.lastName,
  email : req.body.email,
  address : req.body.address,
  country : req.body.country,
  isBookMark : req.body.isBookMark,
});
// console.log(`before contact - ${JSON.stringify(contact)}`);
// // contact = {...req.body};
// console.log(`before after - ${JSON.stringify(contact)}`);
contact.userID=req.user.id;
// ?console.log(`contact - ${(contact)}`);

const {error} = validateContact(contact);
console.log(`ERROR - ${error}`);
}
 catch(error){
console.log(`contacts - ${error.message}`);
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please post your code as text instead of image? It's much better for helping you out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to validate the mongoose schema class which has its own internal properties. That is what you are seeing in the error. You have two choices here

- Instead of passing contact object, pass `req.body` to your validate function.
- Or extract properties from contact schema and pass that object to validate function.

Hope that helps.

Comment: agreed and make sense as well...
that will solve the problem for sure, but what internally is causing the problem?
Thank You very much for the answer :)  and any idea how to tag the person as I tried with @ operator but I guess it did not work out

Comment: When I do like this it doesn't show the error and that's what your second point is right?

 let contact = new Contact();
 contact = {...req.body};
 contact.userID=req.user.id;
 const {error} = validateContact(contact);
 console.log(`ERROR - ${error}`)

Then there is no error.